# Stack Exchange API case sensitive search?

Tags: discussion, api

I'd like to build a simple app using the Stack Exchange API to search for specific words using a case sensitive search. For example, find questions using the word 'javascript' and/or 'Javascript', but not 'JavaScript'.

I've tried a few test searches using the Stack Exchange API - Advanced Search, using a combination of quotes, but no luck.

Is it possible to do case sensitive searches via the Stack Exchange API?

Comment: As the API probably uses the same search index as on main I highly doubt this is available. At best you could do a case sensitive search on [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) using a collation that matches your needs.

Comment: The SEDE solution does work, though it's a bit manual.