# How do I make a case sensitive search on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, search

I can't manage to make a case sensitive search on Stack Overflow.

I've read the https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching page in details, but nothing is said about that.

For example, let's say it makes sense that I want to search for "Result" with upper case in the R. Typing "Result" or Result gives all answers with result, case insensitive.

Comment: Are you trying to search for a code block containing `Result`?

Comment: No, really for the exact match case sensitive "Result", anywhere in question or answers

Comment: You can't. All queries are normalised for case, this is not something you can disable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to do case sensitive searched via the website or the API.

An alternative is to do a case sensitive search with the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), using a collation that matches your needs ([credit goes to @rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353661/stack-exchange-api-case-sensitive-search#comment496082_353661)), but it is quite slow:

```sql
select
  *
from
  Posts p
where
  p.Body collate Latin1_General_CS_AI like '%Result%'
  and p.CreationDate >= '2017-11-01'
```

Comment: @mega6382 Yeah, if I remember correctly the data is updated once a week.

Comment: Ok thanks. Anyone know if it has been ever requested as a feature ?

Comment: The data explorer is updated once a week, on Sundays (UTC night).