# Case sensitive search on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, search

Following answer to my question [How do I make a case sensitive search on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359157/how-do-i-make-a-case-sensitive-search-on-stack-overflow)

I think it makes sense to have a case-sensitive search. I guess in many language syntax expression of the same string can have different meaning depending on the case. 
For example, in Java, "Boolean" and "boolean" are two different things.
In Haskell, "Maybe" is a well-known class, so how can we differentiate a post with some "maybe" in its and the "Maybe" class usage?